# django nginx media files

Tags: django, nginx, media, gunicorn

```
server { 
#listen 443; 
server_name www.site.md; 

location ~* .(jpg|svg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|rar|pdf)$ { 
root /home/ubuntu/giver; 
error_page 404 = 404; 
} 


location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; } 
location /static/ { 
root /home/ubuntu/giver; 
} 

location / { 
include proxy_params; 
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/giver/server/giver/giver.sock; 
} 

location /media { 
root /home/ubuntu/giver/server/giver/giver/media; # your Django project's media files - amend as required 
}
```

As you see, i have added path to media files, but they do not load...
Can someone help me, please? I use django 1.10, nginx, gunicorn on ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `root` to `alias`:

```
location /media/ { 
    alias /home/ubuntu/giver/server/giver/giver/media/;
}
```

then restart:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) you see both syntax with "alias" or "root":

```
location /media/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/giver/server/giver/giver;
}
```

or

```
location /media/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/giver/server/giver/giver/media/;
}
```

Both are valid but the same doc also says that when the location path match the file system path end ("/media" in your case) root is the way to go.